# Meaning of lite friends

Tags: meaning

My English teacher gave me as a homework to explain what "lite friends" means... I searched on the internet but I could not find anything useful.
Please help me! Thanks a lot!!

Comment: The teacher is probably asking for your *opinion* of what this expression might mean, based on the two words "lite" and "friends".   You can find many examples of "lite" on the internet.

Comment: Are you sure the assignment didn't mean to ask about _life_ friends? The phrase "lite friends" is not idiomatic insofar as I know.

Comment: I have to explain these 2 words together, not separately..

Comment: No , it is "lite friends"..That is how it says in my book.

Answer (score 2):

**lite** is a commercialism/advertising spelling for "light".  Fatty foods which have had some of the fat removed are said to be "lite".  Beer with reduced caloric content is said to be "lite". An app lacking some of the features of the full app can be called "lite".  The word has been adopted into the general vocabulary to mean "something which is less than the 'real' thing in some way". A "lite friend" *might* be a casual acquaintance or a friend you know only from online chat rooms but have never met in person, or a friend who cannot be counted on when you need them.  It is not a standard collocation, and so we can only make plausible guesses.